# Main page has a backstretch applied to all pages but want to remove it on a certain page

Tags: destroy, jquery-backstretch

The designers for our site set a backstretch jquery to the entire site. I am making a subpage that I don't want to have a backstretch on. I'm not quite sure how to go about it. I attempted a .destroy and a .remove but still didn't receive the outcome I needed. [This is the page I am editing](https://www.ondaguey.com/single.php/order/restaurant/spadefoot-nursery/34). The patterned bottom is the backstretch that was applied to the whole site.
The code that applies the backstretch is listed below.  Any help on how to change the backstretch to just a blank slate or remove it off this page?
  `$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#carousel .background').backstretch(['/editable/templates/default/images/Mixed_Icon_Terracotta_BG.png'], {duration: 4500, fade: 750});
  });`

Comment: Please include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of just giving the link to the website

Comment: I added the backstretch code that was applied by the developer. He insists that it's impossible to override that jquery. Any idea on how I can just turn it off?